# Remove duicated rows where column A and B are swapped in the duplicate entry

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have an issue where I need to remove duplicated table entries but the entries aren't exactly unique. There are 2 ids, id1 and id2.  And in half of the files, these are swapped in id1 and id2. They are not sequential in the list and I am having trouble removing them.

I am having such a brain fart over this.  I have included a part of the table as follows.  You can see that the parts in bold should match as they are identical except for this. There are 2304 lines in the file without the header and 1152 are duplicated.

| ID1 | ID2 | Sample | Gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **S01-A01** | **S25-A01** | BA159_0 | AIM2 |
| S01-A02 | S25-A02 | BA15_0 | MMP8 |
| S01-A17 | S25-A17 | BA144_0 | SERPING1 |
| **S25-A01** | **S01-A01** | BA159_0 | AIM2 |

I tried messing around with for loops to check if the sample and gene were identical but my logic is off.

```
id_1 <- c("S01-A01", "S01-A03", "S01-A17", "S25-A01", "S29-A39", "S05-A39", "-99")
id_2 <- c("S25-A01", "S25-A02", "S25-A17", "S01-A01", "S05-A39", "S29-A39", "-99")
Sample <-c("BA159_0", "BA15_0", "BA144_0", "BA159_0", "BA183_0", "BA183_0", "-99")
Gene <- c("AIM2", "MMP8", "SERPING1", "AIM2", "S100A8", "S100A8", "-99")
value1 <- c(-1.9975984661369099, 4.7789368498721396 , 3.3080754647069801, 6.9507934374320604, 2.55279730894866, 1.38567349551152, -99)
value2 <- c(-2.0548041003070598, 4.5115336458523103, 3.2588723737573799, 6.9433118002602097, 2.5897834603682202, 1.4031532547429899, -99)
Mean <- c(-2.026201, 4.645235, 3.283474, 6.947053, 2.571290, 1.394413, -99 )
SD <- c(0.040450492, 0.189082619, 0.034791839, 0.005290316, 0.026153158,0.012360056, -99)
df <- data.frame(id1 =id_1, 
                 id2=id_2, 
                 Sample=Sample, 
                 Gene=Gene,
                 value1=value1,
                 value2=value2,
                 Mean=Mean,
                 SD=SD)
 
dropvec = c()
    idvec =c()
    for (i in 1:length(df$ID1))
    {
       for (j in 1:length(df$ID2))
       {
          if(df$Sample[i] == df$Sample[j] && df$Gene[i] == df$Gene[j] && i != j)
          {
             idvec
             if(df$ID1[i] %in% idvec)
             {
                print(paste("ID ",df$ID1[i], " is in idvec"))
             }
             else {
                print("ID is NOT in idvec")
                idvec=c(idvec, df$ID2[j], df$ID2[i])
                dropvec = c(dropvec, j)
                
             }
    
          }
       }   
    }
```

I would appreciate any help on this.  Thanks. I updated my code to have the data frame in it based on advice.  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry.  Should I add more data to the table or include the df?  Sorry, I am new to posting questions.

Comment: no problem. yes, you should include the code that others can copy and paste, so that they have your example data in memory right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```r
df[!duplicated(cbind(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df[-(1:2)])), ]

#       ID1     ID2  Sample     Gene
# 1 S01-A01 S25-A01 BA159_0     AIM2
# 2 S01-A02 S25-A02  BA15_0     MMP8
# 3 S01-A17 S25-A17 BA144_0 SERPING1
```

Comment: This works really well on the small test dataset but I find that it doesn't work on my large dataset.  I still have the dups left.

Comment: @lmrogers34 you need to tell me in what situations dups are left, or I cannot know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Trying to figure that out myself. It looks like the input.  Trying to figure out what Is missing.

Comment: @DarrenTsai: I don’t think there’s anything wrong with your code. I suspect it’s a data issues. Leading or trailing spaces are obvious candidates. But, as you say, without access to the “larger dataset” it’s something OP needs to work out for themselves.

Comment: Yep I am sure it is something wrong with my dataset,  I will update in the comments when I figure out the issue.

Comment: When I add all my columns to the exampleit stops working.,  So it is something to do with my numerical columns not trailing characters.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, based on the tidyverse...

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- read.table(textConnection("ID1     ID2     Sample  Gene
S01-A01     S25-A01     BA159_0     AIM2
S01-A02     S25-A02     BA15_0  MMP8
S01-A17     S25-A17     BA144_0     SERPING1
S25-A01     S01-A01     BA159_0     AIM2"), header=TRUE)

d %>% 
  # Ensure IDs are in a consistent order
  mutate(
    T1=ifelse(ID1 < ID2, ID1, ID2),
    T2=ifelse(ID1 < ID2, ID2, ID1)
  ) %>% 
  # Remove redundant ID columns
  select(-ID1, -ID2) %>% 
  # Ensure uniqueness
  unique() %>% 
  # Restore original IDs
  rename(ID1=T1, ID2=T2)
  Sample     Gene     ID1     ID2
1 BA159_0     AIM2 S01-A01 S25-A01
2  BA15_0     MMP8 S01-A02 S25-A02
3 BA144_0 SERPING1 S01-A17 S25-A17
```

@gaut's comment about providing a minimal reproducible example is apposite.  (Here, we needed a version of your test data provided by `dput()`.)  But you caught me on a good day.

Comment: This also works on a smaller test dataset but doesn't seem to work on my larger dataset.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It has gone from 2305 rows to 2216.  But I still have issues with a duplicate.  It looks like ID1 and ID2 are the same so I can just remove duplicates on it and it should work.

Comment: Without access to your larger dataset, it’s impossible to say why for sure. However, given the algorithm is correct, it suggests the issue is with the data. One obvious thing to check is for leading and trailing spaces in `ID`s that *appear* identical.

Comment: Thanks,  There must be something wrong with the data I will have to investigate as both your answers work on the test data so clearly I am having issues with the data.  Thanks for your help.